# Different Next and Previous Text for each Slide in Flexslider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I have created a flexslider using a wordpress custom post.

I have 6 posts in total and 6 slides that are pulled out from the content of these posts.

I need to change Text for "Next" and "Previous" as the title of the next and previous post in the slide.

Here is the jQuery code I am using currently:

```
$('#ethosBotSection').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideToStart: 0,
            useCSS: false,
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: false,
            slideshow: false,
            manualControls: '.ethosNav li',
            start: function(slider) {
                $('.ethosNav li').click(function() {
                    $('.flexslider').show();
                    var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel")
                    var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo)
                    if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
                        slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please show your code example on jsbin / jsfidle  ( there several versions of flexslider - it will be faster to see your code as is )

Comment: Here is the jQuery Code I am using to run the slider and for next, previous buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/u1qud2u1/

Comment: please add your html and css to it too - we need to see a working example

Comment: If you already has working code and you just need to update text - try just set after callback and inside it do somethind like $('#ethosTopSection').text('New text')

Comment: but i think you need to use the after function something like the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353520/flexslider-after-event-not-firing-or-correctly-formed) but instead of using the currentSlide you will need to use the next and prev slide (not sure if slider has any properties for them or if you have to calculate them yoursefl)

Comment: Hello, here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u1qud2u1/6/

Comment: Also as I asked earlier I have 6 slides in total and each have a different title, need those titles to be used. You can find the titles wrapped here in this list: <ul class="ethosNav">

Comment: does the next prev control both sliders?  If so which title do you want, the top or the bottom slider title?

Comment: Controls are same for both the sliders, I need to use the bottom slide Titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the following js function:

```
function setText(slider) {
    var prev = slider.currentSlide - 1, // in case slider does not strat at 0
        next = slider.currentSlide + 1;

    if (prev < 0) {
        prev = slider.slides.length - 1;
    }

    if (next == slider.slides.length) {
        next = 0;
    }

    $('#ethosPrev a').text($(slider.slides[prev]).text());
    $('#ethosNext a').text($(slider.slides[next]).text());
}
```

You can use it in the start and after events of your **bottom** (going by the above comments) flexslider initiation:

```
$('#ethosBotSection').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideToStart: 0,
    useCSS: false,
    controlNav: true,
    directionNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
    manualControls: '.ethosNav li',
    start: function (slider) {
        setText(slider);
    },
    after: function (slider) {
        setText(slider);
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u1qud2u1/10/) - Please note I removed the start function from your top flexslider initiation

Answer (score 2):

Use prevText and nextText options:

```
$('#ethosBotSection').flexslider({
  animation: "slide", 
  slideToStart: 0,
  useCSS: false,
  controlNav: true,
  prevText: "Prev Slide", //String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
  nextText: "Next Slide",  // String: Set the text for the "next" directionNav item
  directionNav: false,
  slideshow: false,
  manualControls: '.ethosNav li',
  start: function(slider) {
    $('.ethosNav li').click(function() {
      $('.flexslider').show();
      var slideTo = $(this).attr("rel")
      var slideToInt = parseInt(slideTo)
      if (slider.currentSlide != slideToInt) {
        slider.flexAnimate(slideToInt)
      }
    });
  }
});
```