# Jquery Flexslider Custom Prev/Next Arrow Text in WordPress post loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I am using Flexslider (jquery) in my WP site within a WP_Query loop to create a slider of posts within a certain category. This slider is pulling in the post title and content for each post/slide. I am using custom nav functionality so that the previous and next arrow buttons append the previous and next post title text for each slide on slide change - similar to the [approved answer on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778683/different-next-and-previous-text-for-each-slide-in-flexslider).

**My setup:**

```js
function setText(slider) {
    var prev = slider.currentSlide - 1, // in case slider does not strat at 0
        next = slider.currentSlide + 1;

    if (prev < 0) {
        prev = slider.slides.length - 1;
    }

    if (next == slider.slides.length) {
        next = 0;
    }

    $('#prev-link h6.title').text($(slider.slides[prev]).find( "h2" ).text());
    $('#next-link h6.title').text($(slider.slides[next]).find( "h2" ).text());
      
}
  
 $('#prev-link').on('click', function (slider) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider('prev')
    return false;
})

 $('#next-link').on('click', function (slider) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider('next')
    return false; 
})

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
   slideshowSpeed: 7000, 
   animationSpeed: 1000, 
   controlsContainer: ".bottom-pag",
   directionNav: false, 
   controlNav: false,
   start: function (slider) {
        setText(slider);
    },
  after: function (slider) {
        setText(slider);
    },
  });
```

```html
<div id="bottom-info" class="bottom-pag">
<div class="side left-side">
  <a id="prev-link" href="#">
    <h6><span><svg id="left-arrow" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 63 19"><defs><style>svg#left-arrow, svg#right-arrow .cls-1{fill:#f09905;}</style></defs><polygon class="cls-1" points="17.5 18.74 17.5 12.29 61.5 12.29 61.5 6.29 17.5 6.29 17.5 0.26 1.5 9.5 17.5 18.74"/></svg></span>last
      feature</h6>
    <h6 class="title">previous post title goes here</h6>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="side right-side">
  <a id="next-link" href="#">
    <h6>next feature<span><svg id="right-arrow" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 63 19"><defs></defs><polygon class="cls-1" points="61.5 9.5 45.5 0.26 45.5 6.29 1.5 6.29 1.5 12.29 45.5 12.29 45.5 18.74 61.5 9.5"/></svg></span></h6>
    <h6 class="title">next post title goes here</h6>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the previous and next navigation post titles do not update at the same time the slide changes. The previous and next navigation post title text updates only *after* the slide has finished fading in. I'm trying to get the previous/next navigation post title text to update at the same time the slide is fading in. I've tried using the 'before' flexslider function instead of 'after' to update the prev/next navigation text, which says it fires asynchronously with each slider animation, but it's not working, as it makes the next navigation post title the same as the current slide's post title.

Any idea on how to make the previous/next navigation post titles update at the same time as each slide changes?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried the 'before:' function, but as I said above, when I used 'before:' instead of 'after:', it makes the next navigation post title the same as the current slide's post title. So it appears to be firing before it retrieves the slide that it's transitioning to.

Comment: just change the next to currentslide + 2 and prev to currentslide